# Does X mangle prompt environment variables?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, prompt

I'm starting it with `startx`. Before that I have `PS1` in my environment:

```
$ cat /proc/self/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | egrep '^PS'
PS1=[\u@\H \w] 
PS3=> 
PS2=> 
PS4=+
```

From inside `X` I get:

```
$ cat /proc/self/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | egrep '^PS'
PS3=> 
PS4=+
```

I checked in both `GNOME` and `awesome`. Is it expected behavior? Can I do something about it?

Comment: You'd be better using `env` or even `set` to print your environment: `set | grep '^PS'`.

Comment: @roaima `set` doesn't print only environment variables. `export` does, and has the advantage over `env` that its output is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, X doesn't mangle environment variables. But bash does; specifically, it unsets `PS1` and `PS2` in non-interactive shells:

```
$ PS1='my PS1' PS2='my PS2' PS3='my PS3' PS4='my PS4' bash -c export |grep PS
declare -x PS3="my PS3"
declare -x PS4="my PS4"
```

Bash is probably executed somewhere as part of your login sequence. That's guaranteed if your `/bin/sh` is bash and common even if it isn't.

The prompt is a shell setting, meaningful only in interactive shells, so it doesn't make sense to export it to the environment. Set it as part of your shell's interactive initialization file `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: First, you must be right. I just wanted to inform you that I tried to make `bash` startup files as minimalistic as possible. I left only `/etc/profile` with exporting `PS1..4`. I still couldn't see `PS1..2` inside `X`. And yes, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`. The second thing... I just tried to follow the idea that things that apply to the whole session are to go into `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score -1):

*I'm going to assume you're running `bash` as your shell. If you're running something else the specifics will vary but the approach will remain much the same.* To confirm your login shell, run this command: `getent passwd "${USER:-$(id -nu)}" | awk -F: '{print $NF}'`

I suspect that your prompt is defined in `.profile` or `.bash_profile` and is set (once) when you log in to your terminal. When you call `startx` and open a terminal it "knows" it's not a login session so calls `.bashrc` instead.

You can confirm this with the following command, the result of which you might like to reference in your Question: `grep '\<PS.*=' .profile .bash_profile .bashrc`

My recommendation would be to configure your GUI terminal application to force a login shell (assuming such an option exists in your installation).

As an alternative, review the files `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and `.bashrc`, and move one-off startup code to a new file such as `.bash_once` and code that needs to be repeated for each instance of `bash` to a new file such as `.bash_everytime`. You can then `source .bash_once` and `source .bash_everytime` appropriately from the now-empty `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, and `.bashrc`.

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting at with this answer. Forcing a login shell in terminals would solve this particular problem, but it's a bad idea since it introduces a whole slew of other problems (like not having the prompt in shells that aren't directly invoked from the user's favorite terminal emulator).

Comment: @Gilles it was an easy option in case x-yuri wasn't familiar enough with a Linux-based system to do anything else. The approach I take on my own systems is similar to that which I described starting "As an alternative...".